# Trouble solving a specific KVL KCL question

Tags: homework, kirchhoffs-laws

Now I know this is newbie-ish kinda question but I was going over the basics of KCL and KVL, and encountered this problem:
[image: The question]

[image]

For 1., I determine the drop using Ohm's law, ie. 2V
for 2-4 things get confusing. I apply KVL and KCL as follows:
[image]

For KVL1: I2R2+Vs1-I3R3=0 
=> -2V+12V-2V should be 0 but it isn't! 
For KVL2: I3R3-Vs2-I1R1=0 
=> 2-10-8I1=0 => I1= -1A 
For KCL1: I1+I2=-2 
=> I2= -2+1= -1A

But all of those show up as wrong. What's wrong with my analysis? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like an information error in the question to me. Maybe R3 should be 5 ohms and, by implication, I1 = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The voltages around the upper loop should sum to zero.  There is something wrong with the problem statement